# Error in code for parsing arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i learned bash very recently, and i'm trying to read arguments for my script. So i wrote this, but i get an error (and vim has highlited in pink the last double parenthesis in the 4th line)

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++ )); do
  if [[ ${!i:0:1} == "-" ]] && ! [[ ${!i:1} =~ [^a-zA-Z]+ ]]; then
    for (( j=1; j<=$(($(expr length ${!i})-1)); j++ )); do
      if [[ ${!i:j:1} == "s" ]]; then
        k=$((i+1))
        if [ -e ${!k} ]; then
          echo $(realpath ${!k})
        fi
      elif [[ ${!i:j:1} == "o" ]]; then
        echo "Running script without output!"
      fi
    done
  fi
done
```

I get the following error when i run `./test -so doc1`

```
./tests2: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./tests2: line 13: `    done'
```

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with my script?

Comment: Usually, if you are using indices, you are doing something wrong. What is it you are actually trying to match? There is probably a much simpler, much more idiomatic solution.

Comment: I don't know what an indice is :S. But i was just trying to check for all the parameters given, and then check if a parameter contains multiple letters, such as "rm -rf ..."

Comment: Also, read about the `getopts` command in the `bash` man page.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on `getopts` i'll check that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually looks like you've encountered a bug in bash itself!

Bash fails to handle `$(command substitution)` when used inside `$((arithmetic expansion))` inside arithmetic for loops:

```
$ for (( ; ; $(( $(echo 1) )) )); do echo "running"; break; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

It's not just an issue with the extra `))`: bash handles that nesting just fine:

```
$ for (( ; ; $(( 1 )) )); do echo "running"; break; done
running
```

And it works just fine with deprecated backticks instead of `$(..)`

```
$ for (( ; ; $(( `echo 1` )) )); do echo "running"; break; done
running
```

It's also fine within `((arithmetic commands))` in general, it's just arithmetic for loops that are affected:

```
$ while (( $(( $(echo 1) )) )); do echo "running"; break; done
running
```

So yes, congrats, it appears to be a bash bug! I don't know whether this is a known issue, but for now you can rewrite it as suggested in one of the other posts, or preferably use `getopts`.

Comment: Well thanks for doing some tests regarding this and finding out it was a bug! Do you think i should rename my post to `Potential bug in for loops (bash)` ?

Comment: Of course, arithmetic expansion in a for loop is normally unnecessary since the for loop is already an arithmetic context. So there is an easy workaround.

Comment: Ahhh! Ok i was still not getting what those double parenthesis meant. I do understand now that those double parenthesis i added where useless, and it worked perfectly without them: `for (( j=1; j<=$(expr length ${!i})-1; j++ )); do` Thanks @rici!

Comment: @AmineKchouk: it is still a bug in bash and someone should report it.

Comment: Maybe it has been fixed in earlier versions. I just checked and i'm using Bash version 4.3.46(1), but you can see on [Bash's website](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/bash/) and they seem to be at version 4.4.12. I'm on Ubuntu 16.10 Server 64-bit, with apt packages up to date.

Comment: @AmineKchouk I checked it with 4.4.12. Same symptom.

Comment: Not sure why, but further testing shows the following works instead :-     for (( ; ; $(( <(echo -n 1) )) )); do echo "running"; break; done ... I am also wondering at what point this would ever be required?  Is it a bug to use something the way it is not intended??

Comment: @AmineKchouk: You stumbled over the bug, so you have the honour to report it  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the nested `(( ... ))` in the inner for loop.  You can change your code to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=1; i<=$#; i++ )); do
  if [[ ${!i:0:1} == "-" ]] && ! [[ ${!i:1} =~ [^a-zA-Z]+ ]]; then
    lim=$(($(expr length ${!i})-1))
    for (( j=1; j<=$lim; j++ )); do
      if [[ ${!i:j:1} == "s" ]]; then
        k=$((i+1))
        if [[ -e ${!k} ]]; then
          echo $(realpath ${!k})
        fi
      elif [[ ${!i:j:1} == "o" ]]; then
        echo "Running script without output!"
      fi
    done
  fi
done
```

Comment: So i can't put a double parenthesis inside another double parenthesis?